# immutable js update a key in Map

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

So I have an Immutable js map:

```
{
 title: "item 1",
 title2: "item 2",
 title3: "item 3"
}
```

I want to update the keys, so it will become:

```
{
  new title: "item 1",
  title2: "item 2",
  title3: "item 3"
}
```

so far with `update()` and `set()` I can only update the values? Is it possilbe to update the key or do I need to convert it before I can update the keys?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you can use [mapKeys](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/mapKeys) as :

```
var map = Immutable.Map({
  new title: "item 1",
  title2: "item 2",
  title3: "item 3"
});

map = map.mapKeys(k => {
  if (k === "title1") 
    return "newTitle";
  return k;
});
```

Comment: Perfect! Works a charm

Answer (score 8):

another, more direct, approach is to use `delete`

```
var map = Immutable.Map({
  title: "item 1",
  title2: "item 2",
  title3: "item 3"
});

map = map.set('new title', "item 1")
    .delete('title');
```

or

```
map = map.set('new title', map.get('title'))
    .delete('title');
```

Comment: This answer is probably faster, it doesn't have to go over every key in the map.  See e.g. https://jsperf.com/immutable-map-change-key/1.

Comment: Some more detail: `Map.mapKeys` cannot be lazy because then `get` would need to iterate over _every_ key in the original map.